# Bash Script for Moving Variable string (files) with wildcard

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I would like to ask some help regarding my script below:

```
#!/bin/bash

year=$(date +%Y)
lastyear=$((year-1)) 
month=$(date +%m)
log="$lastyear$month"

mkdir -p "/root/temp/$lastyear" 
mkdir -p "/root/temp/$lastyear/$month"
cd /root
mv -f "*$log*" "/root/temp/$lastyear/$month"
```

Error Prompt is

> ```
> mv: cannot stat `*201602*': No such file or directory
> ```

My target was to move all the files that has the specific "201602" string in file name to a specific location.
Sample logs files is `OUTXXX-201602XXX`, `INXXX-201602XXX`, `201602XXXX`.

This will be implemented through `crontab`, because there are about 500k+ log files to be transferred and using find will receive a too much argument error T_T.

Any suggestions will help!

Comment: Tried but still same error prompt

Comment: $archivefolder = /root/temp forgot to edit that part

Comment: Side note: you don't need the `mkdir -p "/root/temp/$lastyear"` command, creating that directory is covered by `mkdir -p "/root/temp/$lastyear/$month"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put globbing characters outside of quotes for them to be interpreted.

Try instead:

```
mv -f *"$log"* …
```

The shell will still keep the resulting matches as one word, so this is OK even if the filenames have spaces.

Comment: Lol that was it? I was trying different combination lol.. This work Thank you very much